# Inference vs Training causes different outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using a custom dense layer that scales an output (size 1) between zero and one.

```
class BoundingBoxNumber(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, self_input_shape):
        super(BoundingBoxNumber,self).__init__()

        self.input_shape_custom = self_input_shape
        self.input_shape_accu = 1
        for item in self_input_shape:
            self.input_shape_accu *= item

        self.internal_dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'tanh')

    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs):

        inputs = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
        inputs.set_shape((1, self.input_shape_accu))
        output = self.internal_dense_layer(inputs)
        output = tf.divide(output, 2)
        output = tf.math.add(output, 0.5)

        return(output)
```

I'm also using a custom training loop

```
for epoch in range(50):

    print("Epoch:", epoch, "of 50")

    average_loss = 0

    for iter, item in enumerate(image):
        
        num_bounding_boxes = tf.shape(bb[iter])[0]
        float_target = tf.cast(1/num_bounding_boxes, tf.float32)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            logits = dense_bb_num_layer(item)
            loss = NumLoss(logits, float_target)
            print("Logits:", logits, "Target:", float_target, "Loss:", loss)
        
        average_loss += loss

        call_gradients = tape.gradient(loss, dense_bb_num_layer.trainable_weights)
        call_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(call_gradients, dense_bb_num_layer.trainable_weights))

    average_loss /= len(image)

    print(average_loss)
```

In addition, I'm using a custom loss function:

```
def NumLoss(logits, expected):
    return((logits - expected)**2)
```

When I run the layer inside the training loop, the result is always a float with a value of exactly 0.0 or 1.0, however, when I just call it, it's as expected, a float value between zero and 1.

I'm not sure why this would be the case, and any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to train the layer to output values such as 0.333333, 0.25, 0.125, etc, so it's difficult if it only outputs whole numbers.